# How to programmatically wake an external screen attached to an iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, peripherals

I'm developing a standalone kiosk that is composed of an iPad 2, and an external screen. I have the two connected by cable, and the iPad is locked in a special case to prevent it from disappearing. This case makes the access to the connector impossible.

The problem I have is that when the iPad wakes from sleep (user interaction) the screen often doesn't wake up. Once the screen awake however, there is never a problem of it going to sleep by itself (this rules out a physical connection problem). I manage to wake up screen after several tries of switching on/off the monitor or letting the ipad fall a sleep and then waking it up.

My guess is that the iPad fails to send the signal while the monitor is scanning for it. However, after several tries I get them both to do their things at the right time, and that is when it all starts to work.

Hence the question. Can I programmatically make the ipad scan (send signal to) the external monitor? Ideally I would do it from the app I'm developing, but a standalone app could solve a trick too.

I've looked through the UIScreen Class reference and googled quite a bit, but so far to no avail.

Comment: Sounds like a sync issue. Try a different brand / model for the external device. Samsung e.g. always had issue with properly syncing on Apple devices. Apple screens however do always work reliably on Apple devices ( big surprise :D ).

Comment: Thx. It is an HP external screen. However, changing the screen is not an option. That is why I would like to control it from my app, somehow.